# Collecting data from file using Hive

Tags: hadoop, load, hive, create-table

I Have my data in this format.

```
"123";"mybook1";"2002";"publisher1";
"456";"mybook2;the best seller";"2004";"publisher2";
"789";"mybook3";"2002";"publisher1";
```

the fields are enclosed in "" and are delimited by ;
Also the book name may contain ';' in between.

Can you tell me how to load this data from file to hive table

the below query which i am using now obviously not working ;

```
create table books (isbn string,title string,year string,publisher string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;'
```

if possible i want the userid and year fields to be stored as Int.
Please help

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are missing is `RegexSerDe`. It's very helpful in inserting only a part of text from the input. Your DDL goes like :

```
create table books ( isbn string, title string, year string, publisher string ) 
  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
  WITH SERDEPROPERTIES  (
     "input.regex" = "(?:\")(\\d*)(?:\"\;\")([^\"]*)(?:\"\;\")(\\d*)(?:\"\;\")([^\"]*)\"(?:\;)" ,
     "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s"
    )
  STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

The regex may look complex at the first sight due the escaping and non-capturing groups. Actually it contains 2 groups `(\d*)` & `([^"]*)` placed alternately two times. The non-capturing groups (`(?:)` just helps to remove the unnecessary context. The group `([^"]*)` also take care of ';' inside bookName field.

But nothing comes without a cost. Despite all of its features, `RegexSerDe` supports only string fields. All you can do is to call the default hive UDF `cast` to do the transformation when selecting the data from the table. eg(actual syntax may vary a bit) :

```
 SELECT cast( year as int ) from books;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, One more help with the same data.
instead of using java RegexSerde, how can i use sed command from unix to clean the data and get my output.

i tried to learn about sed command  and found the replace option. So i can remove the " doule quotations.
But how can i handle the extra ; semi colon which comes in the middle of the data

Please help

Regards,
Harish